# Drupal throwing ajax error 200 with autocomplete textfield?

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

In this module I'm creating i'm implementing drupal's autocomplete and it's giving me this error. I can't figure out why..

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: http://localhost/admin/content/searchcontent/autocomplete
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
localhost
@import url("http://localhost/modules/system/system.base.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/system/system.menus.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/system/system.messages.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/system/system.theme.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/themes/seven/jquery.ui.theme.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/misc/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/system/system.admin.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/customheaderimage/css/customheaderimage_style.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/customheaderimage/css/customheaderimage_admin_style.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/custom/searchcontent/searchcontent.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/comment/comment.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/field/theme/field.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/node/node.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/search/search.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/user/user.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/coffee/css/coffee.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/themes/seven/reset.css?mm2qoh");
@import url("http://localhost/themes/seven/style.css?mm2qoh");
Skip to main content
Home
Hello jake
Log out
Administrative toolbarDashboard (View and customize your dashboard.)
Content (Administer content and comments.)
Structure (Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc.)
Appearance (Select and configure your themes.)
People (Manage user accounts, roles, and permissions.)
Modules (Extend site functionality.)
Configuration (Administer settings.)
Reports (View reports, updates, and errors.)
Help (Reference for usage, configuration, and modules.)
Hide shortcuts      
Add content
Find content
Edit shortcuts  
You are hereHome            Add to Default shortcuts      
Search by Title
Show only items where
status 
anypublishednot publishedpromotednot promotedstickynot sticky
type 
anyArticleBasic page
Update options
Operation 
Publish selected contentUnpublish selected contentPromote selected content to front pageDemote selected content from front pageMake selected content stickyMake selected content not stickyDelete selected contentUpdate URL alias
TitleTypeAuthorStatusUpdatedOperations 
Update Gloabl Background 
Gloabl Background  newBasic pageadminpublished04/27/2013 - 22:21edit
delete
Update ComComp 
ComComp  newBasic pageadminpublished04/27/2013 - 13:59edit
delete
Update Sidelining 
Sidelining  newBasic pageadminpublished04/27/2013 - 12:27edit
delete
Update Zapper 
Zapper  newBasic pageadminpublished04/27/2013 - 11:54edit
delete
Update About 
About  newBasic pageadminpublished04/27/2013 - 11:49edit
delete
```

It's just returning the page, not the json output..It does this in firefox and chrome that i've checked. Here is the rest of my code to implement it.

```
function searchcontent_menu() {
  $items['admin/content/searchcontent/autocomplete'] = array(
    'page_callback' => 'searchcontent_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

//This form code is in the form setup function
$form['searchcontent_box']['searchcontent_search'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => $keywords,
  '#weight' => -10,
  '#size' => 38,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'admin/content/searchcontent/autocomplete',
);

function searchcontent_autocomplete($string = '') {
  $items = array();
  $items['about'] = 'about';
  $items['contact'] = 'contact';
  drupal_json_output($items);
}
```

I explicitly set the items for testing so that there was no issue with my query.
Can anyone find the error that is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Also I have now tested using user/admin as the path and that works. Seems there is either something wrong with my path or function. Perhaps it won't let me use a path that's inside of admin/content?

Comment: All paths under `admin` are restricted, unless the current user has the right permissions that path will throw a 403

Comment: As i'm logged in as the admin should it being throwing the 403? It did when I was playing with the settings but then once i tried manually going to the path it just redirected me to the page the textfield is on, didn't give me the 403.